# Reusable array to avoid GC allocs with CommandBuffer.DrawMeshInstanced()

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to boost the performance of my command buffer by using
[CommandBuffer.DrawMeshInstanced](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.CommandBuffer.DrawMeshInstanced.html).

As parameters it requires a mesh and an array of matrices where to render the instances.

But how would one write performant code with that?
The array size may change very frequently and recreating new arrays every frame isn't that smart.

To test if the approach works at all I just collected all the matrices mesh by mesh in lists and then passed over each list with List.ToArray().... ending up with a lot of GC allocs of course.

Huh!
Anyone got a recipe?

A key may be the the optional count parameter.
It seems to allow to pass a reusable bigger array but only draw the first [count] matrices.

That would mean...

- Each frame I would put all the meshes and matrices of my MeshRenderers in a
  `Dictionary<Mesh, List<Matrix4x4>>`
- Afterwards I would loop through the meshes in the dictionary. For each I put the matrices in the same reusable array of some larger size before drawing them.
- Finally: Clear the lists in the dictionary

Does that make sense?
A better proposal?

Answer (score 0):

> A key may be the the optional count parameter. It seems to allow to
> pass a reusable bigger array but only draw the first [count] matrices.

**Yes!**

> Each frame I would put all the meshes and matrices of my MeshRenderers
> in a Dictionary<Mesh, List>

**No, not exactly**
Keep your data, for example, as:

```
public class BATCH
{
    public Mesh mesh;
    public Material material;
    public Matrix4x4[] transforms;
    public int count;
}
List<BATCH> batches = new List<BATCH>(100);
```

> Afterwards I would loop through the meshes in the dictionary. For each
> I put the matrices in the same reusable array of some larger size
> before drawing them.

**No. Nie. Non. Nicht. 没有.**

`CommandBuffer.DrawMeshInstanced` doesn't makes any sense if your meshes exist in the scene as `GameObject`s already (at least if this is what your meant there). What you want to do instead is to **make them exist in your data array**.

Note that Matrix4x4 can be moved, rotated animated etc. - the same as any `Transform` out there. This way `alloc` will need to happen only once.

```
var buffer = new UnityEngine.Rendering.CommandBuffer();
foreach( var batch in batches )
{
    // move transforms around, etc:
    int numTransforms = batch.transforms.Length;
    for( int i=0 ; i<numTransforms ; i++ )
    {
        var transform = batch.transforms[i];
        batch.transforms[i] = transform * Matrix4x4.Translate( Vector3.up * Mathf.Sin(Time.time) );
    }

    // modify batch size, if needed:
    batch.count = 100;
    if( batch.count>batch.transforms.Length ) System.Array.Resize( ref batch.transforms , batch.count );

    // draw:
    buffer.DrawMeshInstanced( batch.mesh , 0 , batch.material , -1 , batch.transforms , batch.count );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Andrew!

I should have mentioned that I need to commandBuffer to draw a depth texture. Therefore I don't need to keep record of more than the mesh and the amount of submeshes.
But a Batch data structure might still make sense. I was pretty undecided up to now.

As it's a depth texture the objects do already exist as gameObjects.
And so I wouldn't need to keep their transforms in an array.

Comment: Got it to work... but it's slower than before as this line `reusableTransformMatrixArray[transformIndex] = Transforms[transformIndex].localToWorldMatrix;`
negates the instancing benefits.

LocalToWorldMatrix() and copying the matrix into the array (causing String.memcpy() according to the profiler) are together too costly and ruin it. And I see no way to solve that.

For the memcpy issue see: https://forum.unity.com/threads/optimization-help-for-matrix-calculations.699806/#post-4680236

Comment: `localToWorldMatrix` is costly indeed. This is why I wrote that Instancing makes sense only when no `Transform` components are involved, just matrices (those can be processed on worker threads). Theoretically you can still figure out a creative way for this, for example by imposing a rule that those objects have no parent transforms or most/all of them stand still

Comment: As far as I remember `String.memcpy()` happens when big structs are being copied around the heap and Matrix4x4 is **64 bytes**!

Comment: Yes, restricting it to static objects is what I'm going to do today... 
As I said I want to speed up the rendering of my depth texture which I control by little components I add to the objects to be rendered. I'll add an "IsMoving" option now and only draw the static ones instanced.
Thanks for your reply!